# Select an Element from a DropDown Menu

Tags: html

Suppose I have a DropDown Menu on a webpage containing many entries, say 3000.

Now I want to select the 1515th entry and click submit. Is there an easy way to do that ?

Sample DropDown Menu, I'm talking about : http://goo.gl/NV04Pv

Thanks,
Shubham

Comment: Are you looking for doing this programmatically with JavaScript or how exactly do you intend to "select the 1515th entry"?

Comment: Anything should be fine, manually or programmatically using JS.

Answer (score 2):

Use

`$('.ParentElement option:eq(1515)').prop('selected', true)`

or in older Versions

```
$('.ParentElement option:eq(1515)').attr('selected', 'selected')
```

Comment: I don't have the source code of the page. I just have a page with this dropdown menu. I can only use client side scripts !

Comment: uhhh that *is* client side.

Comment: I have no exp with JS or Client Side scripts ( a CPP developer ). How to run this ? Sorry for the trouble !

Comment: press ctr+ shift + j in your browser

Comment: Woops, thanks for that, but where would the element name go ? How will the script identify which dropbox list ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.navigate ("http://www.google.com/ncr")
Do Until oIE.ReadyState = 4  
oIE.Document.forms("FormName").DropDownFieldHTMLID.options(0).selected=true
```

Line 5 is what you are looking for..

FormName  ==>  is the name of the form    .
DropDownFieldHTMLID ==>   is the name of the select tag

The index starts with 0.

So, select the first element it is 0.
for 9th element it is 8
for nth element it is (n-1)

HTH

Comment: I don't have the source code of the page. I just have a page with this dropdown menu. I can only use client side scripts !

Comment: If you're using Firefox , Right click on the dropdown element and go to inspect element, it should give you the details. Also check the view Source option.

Comment: Yes, but that won't help me to select a element of my choice :)

Comment: oIE.Document.forms("FormName").DropDownFieldHTMLID.options(1514).selected=true





This is all that you'll have to do...

Comment: Got ReferenceError: oIE is not defined in FF Console ! Any pointers ?

Comment: This is VBScript yes?  That is important information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combobox, where in you can type and accordingly you you will get the suggestion in the dropdown. Just a suggestion, as far as i understood your query.

Comment: I don't have access to code of the page, the page already exists ! I can use only client side scripting !

Answer (score 0):

You may just copy-paste this script in the Firebug console to do that:
`document.getElementsByTagName('option')[1014].setAttribute("selected", "selected");`

Comment: Where will the element name go ? In place of option ?

Comment: It will go as it if your document contains only one select box on that page. If it has many, you have to change the script a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript or jquery in that particular page then you can select option dynamically. You can ask user to enter option number and save that using js/jquery and use that option number to select option using this :

```
$('select[name=name] option:eq('+x+')').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

**[Example Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Uztkd/2/)**

Comment: That sounds perfect, I'm bad with JS, can you make this static, like I can pass in the script itself to select element 7 ?

I tried to use the below, but it gives error : 

$('select[name=choice] option:eq('7')').attr('selected', 'selected');

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Uztkd/3/
if you pass 7 in :eq() it will select 8th option, but in the example that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easy answer :

```
document.getElementById("choice").selectedIndex="3";
```

Thanks everyone !